# Stored procedure in entity framework and MVC 3

Tags: entity-framework-4.1

Friends I am building one web application using MVC 3. And I have used Entity framework database first approach.I create model class with my database. Every thing works fine but i could not find any classes for the stored procedure, so that i  could not have desired result.

I am stuck to this so i will be very thankful for the suggestion and solutions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey guys i got the answer. Just you need to follow these steps.

=>Right click on Model.edmx file

=> click on update model from database

=>Then Click the Stored procedure you want to include

=>Go to model browser, there you can see stored procedure and click your stored procedure

=>Then in Add Function Import choose the return of your stored procedure

=> save all

=>Go to solution explorer you can find certain class has been added for your stored procedure

I hope you all get this